# Kivy Photo Chooser

Tags: python, kivy

How can I choose photo in Kivy ?
I couldn't see a module to see and select a photo.

from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
shows files by names

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in widget for displaying photos, the Kivy philosophy is instead to make it easy to build such a thing from component widgets, e.g. in this case layouts and Image widgets probably.

That said, we would be happy to include image browser implementations in the Kivy garden user repository.

Comment: Did this ever happen?